# AjaxFileUpload control is not working with multiview, upload never complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an AjaxFileUpload control in Second View of my MultiView. By default first view of MultiView appears and by clicking on a button I reach to second view which have AjaxFileUpload Control. This control is not uploading any file, the upload alwas stuck at 93% or 99% or 100%.

But when I set second view as default view the AjaxFileUpload Control work without any issue.

Code in WebForm (aspx page):

```
  <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
            <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" onunload="AjaxFileUpload1_Unload"
                onuploadcomplete="UploadComplete" ThrobberID="myThrobber" onload="AjaxFileUpload1_Load"
                oninit="AjaxFileUpload1_Init" />
            <asp:AnimationExtender ID="AjaxFileUpload1_AnimationExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                TargetControlID="AjaxFileUpload1">
            </asp:AnimationExtender>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
```

Code in cs page (aspx.cs):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
string path = Path.GetTempPath();

AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("files/")+ e.FileName);
}

protected void AjaxFileUpload1_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
}
```

What is I am doing wrong, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your question.

This is a known issue, AjaxFileUpload control doesn't work if it's placed on an initially invisible Panel control.

Files can be selected on the client side, but if the user clicks the Upload button then the upload will not be finished and it remains in a failed state.

If we want to solve it, we should place another AjaxFileUpload control inside an invisible HTML div tag on the same page

attaching the same client and server side upload complete event handlers to both AjaxFileUpload control.

Please check follow link, someone has provided a solution.

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27307

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `MultiView` and view control with a `multiple panel`. And create a method that simulated

```
multiview.setactiveview();
Panel1.visible=true; 
Panel2.Visible=false;
```